# Does conda install a different python binary for the same python versions?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

Before installing conda, my system has a python 2.7 installed; then I installed conda for python 2.7 with 64-bits from the [official package for macOS](https://conda.io/miniconda.html).

Now it looks like my python binary has been 'moved' to a different place

```
ss-MacBook-Pro$ which python
/miniconda2/bin/python
```

**Question 1**: Has my old python binary been erased and a new version of Python get installed under /miniconda2/?

---

I then created a new environment with `conda create --name testenv python=2.7`, and the `conda env list`

```
ss-MacBook-Pro$ conda env list
# conda environments:
#
base                  *  /miniconda2
testenv                  /miniconda2/envs/testenv
```

**Question 2**: Did I install a new python binary under `/miniconda2/envs/testenv`? i.e., is the python binary in each environment a separate binary package from base environment or other environments even thought they are the same version?

Answer (score 1):

Installing Anaconda, installs another instance of Python. It won't affect your other installations, but it might change the default python for certain applications. This would append the Anaconda Python path to the `PATH` environment variable in `~/.bashrc` (for Unix). This is one of the parameters that you can set during installation. Your system Python should still be there (probably at `/usr/bin/python`) and any other Python installations you may have had.

Creating another environment installs yet another installation. In fact, you have the option of creating an environment with Python 3. These are kept within the `env` directory within the main Anaconda directory. You can list them with `conda env list`.